# Why do contour labels make contours disappear?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, contour

The sample data is generated as follows,

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.__version__) # 3.3.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, y=0):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < 1, np.logical_and(1 <= x, x < 10), x >= 10], [lambda x: 0, lambda x: (x - 1) / 9 * 1000, lambda x: 1000])

x = np.logspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.logspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
```

I try to plot using the following code, but some contours disappear after calling `clabel`.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=120)
cr = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=3, colors='black')
ax.clabel(cr, inline=True, fontsize=8, fmt='%d')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This issue still appears even when contour linewidth and label font size are decreased.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=120)
cr = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=3, colors='black', linewidths=0.6)
ax.clabel(cr, inline=True, fontsize=3, fmt='%d')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I cannot figure out how to fix the weird behaviours of `contour` and `clabel`, and I suspect it is due to  their incompatibility with log scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a problem of the log axes, especially around the asymptote zero. However, why not defining the log axes before plotting, so matplotlib can take this into consideration when plotting?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.__version__) # 3.3.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, y=0):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < 1, np.logical_and(1 <= x, x < 10), x >= 10], [lambda x: 0, lambda x: (x - 1) / 9 * 1000, lambda x: 1000])

x = np.logspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.logspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=120)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
cr = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=3, colors='black')
ax.clabel(cr, inline=True, fontsize=8, fmt='%d')

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]